# Eclipse Jobs API using Thread Pools?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-rcp, threadpool

is Eclipse 3.0 Jobs API using any internal thread pool for executing jobs?
or is it creating a new thread each time a job is scheduled (about to be started)?

if it doesn't use any thread pooling, is it somehow possible to use Jobs with Java's ExecutorService so that scheduled jobs will reuse existing threads from the Executor's pool?

if not then last question, is there a chance to provide progress feedback in the Eclipse progress view (as I'd do with Jobs IProgressMonitor) but from within a regular Java Thread?

I really like the features Jobs API provides (especially progress monitoring and cancellation) but I'm a bit concerned about the overhead it may introduce to the main UI thread if it doesn't use thread pooling and the jobs are scheduled really often.

thanks in advance!

regards,
jb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse Jobs do use a fixed number of worker threads. Jobs are allocated to these worker threads, based on the priorities.

I cannot find any documentation stating that, but if you start your Eclipse instance in debug mode, you can see some worker threads in the thread list - these are the threads jobs are executed in.

Comment: yes, I can see some worker threads in debug mode - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: what is more, Jobs thread pool doesn't seem to be fixed, it grows as needed and shrinks after a while of inactivity - this is exactly something I wanted to see - thanks again! :)